# Rmarkdown Numbering between Chunks becoming code chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I'm trying to do some hirarchical numbering on Rmarkdown which is usually easy, but I'm facing some problem that I'm not sure if it's a bug or if I am missing something.

If I run the following Inside a Rmarkdown (even here on github) the second numbering (`2. number2`) becomes a chunk of code instead of continuing the previous count which was expected to be ii, and I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

````
1. RR
    1. number1

```{r}
print(head(iris))
```

    2. number2


```{r}
print(head(iris))
```
````

[image: Output]

[Edit: added output image]

Comment: I am not sure based on this why or what is really going on, but my experience with 'tainted' chunks i that you may need to add two spaces after '```'   as well as a hard return

Comment: Added an output image, spaces doesn't seems to fix it

Comment: is yoru concern that the `print(head(iris))` shows

Comment: No, it was just an example.
The problem is that the 2. Number2 is inside of a output like instead of continuing the previous numbering

Comment: You mean the box around the 2.sadadas?

Comment: Yes, had eddited for better naming but looks like yours didn't update yet.

Comment: I added some suggestions below

Answer (score 0):

Try turning echo off so you do not get the code boxes around the output, and instead of using print, try using the package `knitr` and calling cable, it makes a nicely formatted table which will not interfere with your text and the echo kills the printing of the code box

````
1. RR
```{r echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```

2. major stuff
  i) some sub-stuff
     A. more-sub stuff
     B. more-sub stuff

```{r echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```
````

[image]

Comment: The quotes are to keep stack from removing the ticks, but remove the quotes from the code you use,

Comment: Doesn't change, the tables change format as expected but the number in the middle still inside a box.
Looking at your example realized that if I remove the 2 tabs to make it to a second level it knits properly, but it was supposed to be a spaced, a sencond level of a list.

Comment: so it should be a space, the number a period and a space.... for ordered and a space a `-` or a `*` for unordered....never had them break unless there was a problem with formatting...

Comment: I'll get this as a tool limitation then. Thanks though.
Should I mark as answered?

Comment: Well...I was able to get it to work...so the question is why can you not...are you using ) after the second order lists items and then back to spaces and . for the third order?

Comment: The white boxes are a facet of HTML, and they are there to separate code from text, but if you use a data table method and proper list formatting you can jump from chunk to text to chunk and back